# RStudio Error: Unused argument ( by = ...) when fitting gam model, and smoothing seperately for a factor

Tags: smoothing, subscript, gam

I am still a beginnner in R. For a project I am trying to fit a gam model on a simple dataset with a timeset and year. I am doing it in R and I keep getting an error message that claims an argument is unused, even though I specify it in the code.

It concerns a dataset which includes a categorical variable of "Year", with only two levels. 2020 and 2022. I want to investigate if there is a peak in the hourly rate of visitors ("H1") in a nature reserve. For each observation period the average time was taken, which is the predictor variable used here ("T"). I want to use a Gam model for this, and have the smoothing applied differently for the two years.

The following is the line of code that I tried to use

```
`gam1 <- gam(H1~Year+s(T,by=Year),data = d)`
```

When I try to run this code, I get the following error message

```
`Error in s(T, by = Year) : unused argument (by = Year)`
```

I also tried simply getting rid of the "by" argument

```
`gam1 <- gam(H1~Year+s(T,Year),data = d)`
```

This allows me to run the code, but when trying to summon the output using summary(gam1), I get

`Error in` [<-`(`*tmp*`, snames, 2, value = round(nldf, 1)) :  subscript out of bounds`

Since I feel like both errors are probably related to the same thing that I'm doing wrong, I decided to combine the question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you load the {mgcv} package or the {gam} package? The latter doesn't have factor by smooths and as such the first error message is what I would expect if you did `library("gam")` and then tried to fit the model you showed.

To fit the model you showed, you should restart R and try in a clean session:

```
library("mgcv")

# load you data

# fit model
gam1 <- gam(H1 ~ Year + s(T, by = Year), data = d)
```

It could well be that you have both {gam} and {mgcv} loaded, in which case whichever you loaded last will be earlier on the function search path. As both packages have functions `gam()` and `s()`, R might just be finding the wrong versions (masking), so you might also try

```r
gam1 <- mgcv::gam(H1 ~ Year + mgcv::s(T, by = Year), data = d)
```

But you would be better off only loading {mgcv} if you wan factor by smooths.